# mvc have different form depending model is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, model

Im am developing an MVC 5. I have the same View for insert and update. I want to call different Method depending on it.

I want to do something like this.

[image]

- Is that posible?
- What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

That's a typical scenario. Take out all that conditional code from your view, all you have to do is have one form with one action. You'll have a UserID property, make sure it has a value if you have a user and is 0 when you want to create one.

In your controller, that's where you check the value of that UserID, if it's 0 then you need to create one, if it has a value then you fire the update.